# Where to place API calls to third party

Tags: java, reactjs, api, frontend, backend

I'm building a news feed website where I will post the news from another api. The api requires my credentials to connect, so is it better to place the api requests in backend or there is a way to do it securely through front end.

Right now I have backend components only for user data, not for news (Java and Spring MVC)
Front end is with React JS. Thank you in advance

I would want to place it in the front end since it will be faster

Comment: if you need to store credentials then that should be done from the backend or else anyone can view these credentials with a simple network inspection in the browser.

Comment: yeah, I know. but I was wondering if there is any way around to do it still from front end, because it would make it work faster. And in general I'm curious how the news websites actually do it. Thank you btw!

Comment: use a proxy api, let the backend handle the auth and forwarding the request, the client can pass whatever params and stuff are needed. But dont do something that will expose your secrets for the sake of negligible speed improvements.

Comment: Will try to do that. And thank you for quick responses

Comment: I suspect news sites use backends for all of their content, maybe even server side rendering, secrets can't live in the client (compiled code or runtime requests) as those can be easily inspected and stolen. Whats awesome is you can go to a site and inspect the page. look at what they are doing and get ideas if you're stuck, give it a shot :)

Comment: Sure thing :) hope that is helpful